# Exists condition in Drools

Tags: drools, optaplanner

The context is employee shift rostering in OptaPlanner with Drools rules. Assume that I have some shifts and that I need to check if any of the shifts is in a list of pre-defined shifts to assign. The latter list of shifts to assign is, say, `[S1,S2,S3]`; I need to match the following condition (I use a colon as a "such that"):

```
exists s in [S1,S2,S3] : forall shift (shift != s)
```

How could I implement such a rule in Drools?

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will match if there is no `Shift` that is member of `[S1, S2, S3]`.

```
not Shift( this memberOf [S1, S2, S3] )
```

Not sure if the list literal `[S1, S2, S3]` is Drools-compatible but I assume it's going to be something dynamic that will be inserted into working memory as a fact.

Comment: Actually, this implementation doesn't seem to work: I need to check if *every* member of `Si` of `[S1,S2,S3]` has at least one `Shift` such that (roughly) `Shift = Si`, or (negation): there is one element `Si` of `[S1,S2,S3]` such that no `Shift` is (of type) `Si`.

Comment: My quantifier must work with the elements of the list `[S1,S2,S3]`, not with the objects of the Drools session (`Shift`).

Comment: I think I understand now. This answer is wrong. I'll start from scratch and delete this later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to represent the list of shifts to be assigned `[S1, S2, S3]` as a different type of fact (`ShiftToAssign`):

```
Shift { // planning entity
  String id;
  LocalDateTime: time;
  Emploee employee;
}

ShiftToAssign { // planning fact
  String id;
}
```

Then, instead of adding/removing elements to the pre-defined list of shifts to assign, you simply add them to `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty`. They will be automatically inserted into Drools working memory and so you'll be able to match your condition like this:

```
$s : ShiftToAssign     // equivalent to: for each Si in [S1, S2, S3]
not Shift(id == $s.id) // equivalent to: there is no Shift whose id is member of the list
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got the idea... Thanks. I need to check if the line of implementation that you suggest is actually compatible with the model that I have (I guess you imagined that my model/domain is in fact more complicated than the one I sketched here).